# Python variable and brackets

Tags: python

I have some code in Lambda and want to secure password with Lambda Environment variables.

Now code look like this:

```
command = ssm_client.send_command( \
InstanceIds=[InstanceId], \
DocumentName='AWS-RunPowerShellScript', \
Parameters={ \
  "commands":[" \
    $pass = ConvertTo-SecureString superPassword123 -AsPlainText -Force; \
    $creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList kagarlickij\Admin,$pass; \
    Remove-Computer -ComputerName $(hostname) -Credential $creds -Verbose -Restart -Force \
"]} )`
```

How can I replace `superPassword123` with `os.environ['DomainPassword']` taking into account all those brackets?

Comment: Where would you switch to 'DomainPassword'. Is it the `$pass` in the `-ArgumentList`? Sorry, I don't know whether I have enough context on what you're doing / PowerShell.

Comment: I need to replace `superPassword123 ` with `os.environ['DomainPassword']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the password (or any other hardcoded substring in python with string formatting:

```
"commands":[" \
    $pass = ConvertTo-SecureString {pw} -AsPlainText -Force; \
    $creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList kagarlickij\Admin,$pass; \
    Remove-Computer -ComputerName $(hostname) -Credential $creds -Verbose -Restart -Force \
".format(pw = os.environ['DomainPassword'])
```

Comment: This will expose your password in the shell command, but if it's available in your environment anyway, it won't matter in most cases.

Comment: You mean it is a variable in a PowerShell script? I thought it was an environment variable. How are you using Python here?

Comment: yeah, I send PowerShell command to Windows instance using AWS SSM.
I need Python because Lambda doesn't support PowerShell (PowerShell Core is supported, but it doesn't support work with ActiveDirectory).
And I use Lambda as an action of CloudWatch Events rule.
The target is to remove server from domain when it's terminated by ASG.

Comment: Have you tried my code? It should work assuming: 1) python can access the password from your environment and 2) python is kicking off PowerShell so it can hardcode the password (no variable needed). If you want, you can add a command to PowerShell to store the password for further use.

Comment: Or are you saying your password is generated in PowerShell? Hence, `$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString superPassword123 -AsPlainText -Force`. In that case, you might want to add a Powershell Command to write it out to an environment variable or even a text file (if you're destroying the machine anyway).

Comment: No, it's not generated in PowerShell, it's currently hardcoded and all I need is to replace `superPassword123` with `os.environ['DomainPassword']`